# How to connect spark from HAWQ via JDBC/ODBC driver?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, hawq

Nice to meet you all. I'm Anqing,a trainee working in China.
  I'm trying to connect spark from HAWQ via JDBC driver. I know that there is a problem looks like as mine, but I have not solved my issues.
  Can you help me how to deal with it?Please tell me in detail.
  Thanks.

Zheng Anqing

Comment: Please provide more details.  We need the code you have tried along with the errors you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are trying to connect to HAWQ database from spark, you may use Postgres 8.4 JDBC driver (since HAWQ is based on Postgres).